# How can I transform this information to queries?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have some information I want to transform into queries but I don't know if it's possible (with regex on sublime text? or other?)

I have a file with a lot of cars brand and their models in this form

```html
AUSTIN;
1100
HEALEY
MINI
BMW;
X1
X3
FERRARI;
CALIFORNIA


INSERT INTO `car_model` (``,` name_model`, `id_brand`) VALUES ('', '1100', '1'), ('', 'HEALEY', '1'),('', 'MINI', '1');
INSERT INTO `car_model` (``,` name_model`, `id_brand`) VALUES ('', 'X1', '2'), ('', 'X3', '2');
INSERT INTO `car_model` (``,` name_model`, `id_brand`) VALUES ('', '1100', '3');
```

I need to transform every brand to an ID and add every model to this ID.
like what I did manually.

Example, in the first query `VALUES ('', '1100', '1')` mean `('nothing because it's automatic id', '1100 because it's the model', '1 because it's the first brand')`. 
After each brand there is a `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `readfile()`, then `explode()`, then a couple loops:

```
$vals   =   'AUSTIN;
1100
HEALEY
MINI
BMW;
X1
X3
FERRARI;
CALIFORNIA
';

    function FetchModels($vals)
        {
            // Explode on new lines
            $set    =   explode("\n",$vals);
            // If the array is set and not empty
            if(is_array($set) && !empty($set)) {
                    // Filter empties
                    $set    =   array_filter($set);
                    // Loop through the array
                    foreach($set as $value) {
                            // Search for the semi-colon which
                            // indicates brand name
                            if(strpos($value,';') !== false)
                                // Trim off semi-colon
                                $brand = trim($value,";");
                            else {
                                // If the brand is set, start models
                                if(isset($brand))
                                    $array[$brand][]    =   $value;
                                }
                        }
                }
            // Return the array if made
            return (isset($array))? $array:false;
        }

    // Create array from function
    $array  =   FetchModels($vals);

    if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)) {
            // Loop through the array and insert into db
            $i = 1;
            foreach($array as $brand => $models) {
                    // Set the start of the sql
                    $sql    =   "insert into `carbrand` (`name_model`,`id_brand`) VALUES";  
                    // Loop trough models
                    foreach($models as $name) {
                            $finals[$brand][]   =   "('$name',$i)";
                        }
                    // Add models to the sql
                    echo
                    $sql    .=  implode(", ",$finals[$brand]);

                    // Insert your mysql insert here
                    $i++;
                }
        }
```

**Gives you:**

```
// Original Models array 
// FetchModels()
Array
(
    [AUSTIN] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1100
            [1] => HEALEY
            [2] => MINI
        )

    [BMW] => Array
        (
            [0] => X1
            [1] => X3
        )

    [FERRARI] => Array
        (
            [0] => CALIFORNIA
        )

)

// SQL inserts
insert into `carbrand` (`name_model`,`id_brand`) VALUES('1100',1), ('HEALEY',1), ('MINI',1)
insert into `carbrand` (`name_model`,`id_brand`) VALUES('X1',2), ('X3',2)
insert into `carbrand` (`name_model`,`id_brand`) VALUES('CALIFORNIA',3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask this as a PHP question, I would write a small php script to extract the models and insert them in the database, such as:

```
<?php
// TODO: add database connection with mysqli_connect()
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO car_model (name_model) VALUES ({$data[0]})";
        mysqli_query($sql);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried but some isues :
only models with numbers was inserted and no one had id_brand